# How to host WCF service in console apps

Tags: wcf, host, wcf-hosting

i am learning wcf. so i create wcf project and that has one class. code as follows

```
namespace TestWcfService1
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(string value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", "Welcome " + value);
    }

}
}
```

now when i am trying to add the wcf service reference to my console apps like add service reference and the service url like this **http://localhost:21541/Service1.svc** then i am getting error called **Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:21541/Service1.svc'.**

so i am just not being able to achieve my goal. i know some where i am missing something and that is why i am getting error. so please guide me how to add service ref to console apps. app.config will be updated automatically or do i need to write anything there. help please. thanks

Comment: Is your service _running_? See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)

Comment: i do not know how to check service is running or not. guide me

Comment: i check the service is running or not the got error "Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the configuration double check that the service behavior is set up to allow service metadata:

`<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>`

and in the services section add a metadata endpoint

`<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>`

EDIT: Example config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="BehaviorConfig"
      name="[ServiceNameGoesHere]">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="[ServiceContractHere]">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="BehaviorConfig">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
        set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
        to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

There is a pretty good writeup on Dan Rigsby's blog called [WCF Metadata](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/27/wcf-metadata/) which explains in greater details about setting up the MEX endpoints (which are required for Add Service Reference to work).

Comment: can u give me sample web.config all entries for wcf service

Comment: i thought web.config related all entries will be added automatically but i need to hand code it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your WCF service project in your solution, you can right click your console application and say "Add Service Reference" and then click the "Discover" button and that should find it for you. 
And Yes, the config file needs to be updated with behaviors and endpoints and so forth.

Look at: [WCF Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660480/wcf-metadata-contains-a-reference-that-cannot-be-resolved)