# Cannot obtain metadata from <redact>. Client and service binding may be mismatched

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract, known-types

Áfter some changes in a `WCF DataContract`, I suddenly couldn't access the service anymore. Using Microsoft's `WCF Test Client` to obtain the interface I got the following error message

> Error:  Cannot obtain Metadata from  If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation bla-bla.
>
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: .
>   Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by
>   service
>
> The client and service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server
>   returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the
>   content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the
>   expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.

[A question with the exact same error message was asked and answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660480/wcf-metadata-contains-a-reference-that-cannot-be-resolved)

In that question the cause was an error in the configuration file. Because my configuration file worked yesterday, I was pretty sure the config file is not the cause of the problem.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(nameof(DerivedClass))]
public class BaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
     public decimal Value {get; set;}
}
```

It took me several hours to find the source of the problem. I thought it wise to share the knowledge, in case someone uses the same error message as a search string.

Quiz: The code compiles, the service runs, but the metadata can't be obtained. Can you find the error in the code above?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `KnownTypeAttribute`. If you want a complete derived class as a known type, you should use the constructor with Type parameter instead of string parameter, so: [KnownType(**typeof**(DerivedClass))]

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass))]
public class BaseClass
{
```